# Input change event will not work on input formControl?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

```html
<div class="start-time-wrapper">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="From"
  [ngxTimepicker]="start" [format]="24"
  formControlName="startTime"
  (change)="startTimeChange($event, i)">
```

```js
startTimeChange(startTime, i){
  this.orderForm.value.date[i].time.endTime = this.addMinutes(startTime);
  console.log(this.orderForm.value);
}

createItem(): FormGroup {
  return this.formBuilder.group({
    date: [''],
    time: this.formBuilder.group({
      startTime: [''],
      endTime: [''],
    }),
  });
}
addItem(): void {
  this.date = this.orderForm.get('date') as FormArray;
  if (!this.orderForm.value.date[0].date || !this.orderForm.value.date[0].time.startTime || !this.orderForm.value.date[0].time.endTime) {
    this.toastr.error('Please add date & time for continue!');
    this.showError = true;
    return;
  } else {
    this.showError = false;
  }
  this.date.push(this.createItem());
}
```

Hi, I'm working with angular framework. so maybe anyone experienced this.? when we try to add change event on an input fromControl the change event will not work or cannot be triggered. maybe anyone has other way to add change event on formControl input please let me know. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using ReactiveForms, you can utilize the `FormControl.valueChanges` observable directly from your controller to respond to changes.

see: https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  group: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.group = fb.group({example: this.fb.control('')});
    this.group.get('example').valueChanges.subscribe(change => {
      /* changes here */
    })
  }
}
```

#### Expanded Example for FormArray

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-y9zi7z?file=src/app/app.component.ts

The idea is similar for FormArray. We simply need slightly more sophistication to manage our subscription since the FormArray may grow over time.

**summarized**

- Create the FormGroup, and add it to your FormArray
- Subscribe to the valueChanges on the relevant controls in the newly created FormGroup
- Add slightly expanded logic for Subscription cleanup.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy {
  form: FormGroup;
  subscribers: Subscription[];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      parts: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    this.subscribers = [];
  }
}
```

We will have a form array named `parts`

**Getter**

```js
  get partsArray() {
    return (this.form.controls['parts'] as FormArray).controls as FormGroup[];
  }
```

**Template**

```html
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let grp of partsArray">
    <div class="row" [formGroup]="grp">
      <input type="text" formControlName="start">
      <input type="text" formControlName="end">
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**Add Item to array**

```js
  addItem() {
    let array = this.form.get('parts') as FormArray;
    array.push(
      this.fb.group({
        start: this.fb.control(''),
        end: this.fb.control(''),
      })
    );
    this.handleChanges(array.controls[array.length - 1]);
  }
```

**change detection**

```js
  handleChanges(control: AbstractControl) {
    this.subscribers.push(
      control.get('end').valueChanges.subscribe((change) => {
        control.get('start').patchValue(change);
      })
    );
  }
```

For this example I've simply decided to directly set the value of the "start" control to the same value as the "end" control whenever "end" is updated.

**cleanup**

```js
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscribers.forEach((sub) => {
      if (!sub.closed) sub.unsubscribe();
    });
  }
```

Because we create a subscription every time we add a row to our form, we may wish to close all these subscriptions when our component is destroyed to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: But this input is dynamic. It is a form array.

Comment: I updated the code above you can check

Comment: I've updated my answer with a small example using a FormArray to duplicate the value from one control into another.

Comment: let me try. ill update you